# Feeds CSV import taxonomy and file

Tags: nodes, feeds, importing-exporting

I have an interesting use-case.

I have to import a lot of documents (+100) into a specific content type called "Resource".
This content type consists of few taxonomy fields (mapped to a vocabulary), some textfields and PDF file.

What should be the strategy when using Feeds module. Is it possible to have multiple taxonomy terms per field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For taxonomy terms :** 
It is possible, simply delimit your values with commas in your taxonomy field CSV column, and in the Feeds mapping, select "Search taxonomy terms by: Term name" and "Auto create"

Make sure your Drupal field allowed number of values is set to Unlimited (or > 1)

**For files:**

- your file is external and given a URL, feeds will download it and store it
- your file is already stored locally then the URI must be either

  - a stream wrapper (e.g.: public://import/myfile.pdf)
  - a relative path from your docroot
  - an absolute path on your system

Comment: Thanks, and what about the files ?

Comment: Either your file is external and given a URL, feeds will download it and store it; or if it is already stored locally then the URI must be a stream wrapper (e.g.: public://import/myfile.pdf), a relative path from your docroot, or an absolute path on your system

Comment: I am going to give it a try and report in a bit

Comment: Confirmative: External URL works !

Comment: If you consider this answer as good, accept it ;) (I'll update my original answer to add info about file import)

Comment: I did it, sorry for the delay though... :) 
Regards